# Different learning rates for different variables in a custom Keras layer using TensorFlow Agents

Tags: tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning, agent

Following the [Train-a-deep-Q-network](https://www.tensorflow.org/agents/tutorials/1_dqn_tutorial) tutorial from TensorFlow Agents I am implementing a sequential model including one custom layer as a q_net to be passed as an argument to the DqnAgent(..., q_network=q_net, ...) class:

Simplified sketch of the custom layer:

```
class CustomLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, n_layers, activation="linear", name="MyLayer"):
        super(CustomLayer, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.n_layers = n_layers

    self.alphas = tf.Variable(1., trainable=True)
    self.betas = tf.Variable(1., trainable=True)

    ...
```

Part of the code where it is used:

```
layer1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64)
layer2 = CustomLayer(16)
layer3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4)

q_net = sequential.Sequential([layer1, layer2, layer3])

agent = dqn_agent.DqnAgent(
    train_env.time_step_spec(),
    train_env.action_spec(),
    q_network=q_net,
    ...)
```

This custom layer has two distinct sets of trainable tf.Variables, self.alphas and self.betas, (similar to 'self.kernel' and 'self.bias' in a custom dense layer). Now I want to have different learning rates for the two different sets of parameters, which can be achieved using the gradient tape, multiple optimizers and the model.trainable_variables attribute, like it is done in [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/quantum/tutorials/quantum_reinforcement_learning) for the reinforce_update() function:

```
optim_A = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1)
optim_B = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001)

def reinforce_update(states, actions, returns, model):
    ...

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        ...

    grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    for optimizer, w in zip([optim_A, optim_B], [0, 1]):
        optimizer.apply_gradients([(grads[w], model.trainable_variables[w])])
```

However, I am struggling to apply this in the TensorFlow Agents setting, where the training happens through the DqnAgent.train() method.

Is there a way to have different learning rates for different sets of parameters of a custom layer when using the DqnAgent.train() function?

I have tried to somehow modify the DqnAgent.train() function, in order to incorporate multiple optimizers, but I fail to do so.